# xpages: Array prototype functions not working after using fromJson

Tags: json, xpages

in xpages (notes 8.5.3) i'm using the built-in server-side javascript function **toJson** to save a javascript object as json. however, when i use **fromJson** to get the object from the string, i can no longer use my personal prototype functions for the arrays contained in the resulting object.

as an example:

```
var obj0={x:[1,2,3,"x","y","z"]};
var s=toJson(obj0);
var obj1=fromJson(s);

var x0=obj0.x.copy(); // WORKS FINE
var x1=obj1.x.copy(); // ERROR RAISED
```

the error raised is:

> [TypeError] Error calling method 'copy()' on an object of type 'Array
>   [JavaScript Object]'

the function copy() is a simple prototype function for Array and works fine:

```
if(!Array.prototype.copy) {
    Array.prototype.copy=function() { return this.slice(0); }
}
```

the array x1 from above is instanceof Array and supports all built-in Array functions, like slice, join etc. yet, using prototype functions doesn't work.

does anybody know what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: This works fine for me. Have you tested the function on a "clean" system? Because a modification of *Array.prototype* affects the whole server and will resist in the memory...

Comment: in the example above, the protoype functions work fine for the array x0 that i created. that's why i didn't think about an older version of Array.prototype persisting in the memory could cause the problem. also, the whole server has been restarted multiple times without any changes being done to the prototype functions meanwhile. do you still think that the problem occurs due to the memory? if yes, how can i get a "clean" system?

Comment: The server is "clean" after a restart. This was just an idea, because for me it works fine (8.5.3FP1 & 8.5.3). What about your *copy* method? Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: thanks for your help. i added the code for the copy function. as you can see, it is pretty simple and usually does not cause any problems. regarding the error message i get, i don't think that the function itself is the problem, but that the prototype function is just not available for the Array object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of creating an object using fromJson is that only the object data, but none of its methods are added to the created object. Hence, one has to either manually add all the methods, or clone the new object. The following links provide explanations and the code needed to clone a javascript object:

[1. Clone Anything with JavaScript](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone)

[2. Copying an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Interesting articles. But it still confuses me that your provided example works fine for me on different domino versions.

Comment: I was wondering about that too. Maybe the built-in fromJson is different for different domino versions (i'm using 8.5.3 btw)...

Comment: Tested on 8.5.2, 8.5.3, 8.5.3 FP1 & 9.0 ;-)

Comment: Well, then I have absolutely no idea where the problem originates from. I can only say that using my clone function, i.e. replacing "var obj1=fromJson(s)" with "var obj1=cloneObj(fromJson(s))" in the code above, solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Could the problem have something to do with this described by Tommy
http://dontpanic82.blogspot.se/2010/10/xpages-bug-in-fromjson-with-fix.html
Paul Hannan wrote a comment that he has logged a bug report about it, but I don't know if it's fixed in 8.5.3

Comment: thanks for the hint, but the conversion of arrays using fromJson works fine. it's just that the resulting Array objects do not have the prototype functions they should have.

Comment: Could you add a print(obj1.getClass().toString()+" "+obj0.getClass().toString()) and see what it returns?

Comment: @jjtbsomhorst: i added the code, but i get the following error: "[TypeError] Error calling method 'getClass()' on an object of type 'Object [JavaScript Object]'". it seems the function getClass() is not available in SSJS...

Comment: Just wanted to be sure the object returned by the JSON method is actually a Javascript type and not some sort of Java type.